# How to make JSP read JSON returned by the server using JAX-RS?

Tags: java, json, jsp, jax-rs

I am writing my first jax-rs project. I did everything on the server - there is a json object ready to be sent to the client. Now I have to write the client. I am going to use jsp, but I do not understand how to get json. My server code:

```
@Path("/")
public class Server {

    @GET
    public String getData() {
        String json = getJson(); // suppose I have such a method
        return json;
    }
}
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>web</display-name>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>web</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Now I want to add a client (.jsp), but I have no idea how it will be reading that json and how to configure a new .xml. Could you please help? I am searching for more tutorials, but unfortunately I am very pressed for time.

Comment: What you should probably do, is use AJAX (from within a JSP perhaps) to call your REST-service and process its JSON.

Comment: Finally I used a servlet. Received json as a String and parsed it back into json.